# Opening .xsn file from a different site collection

Tags: project-server

I’m trying to open a .xsn file from a certain site collection (Project Server) on the other site collection (in visual web part). My goal is to present an InfoPath form.

.xsn url:

```
http://lp/pwa/projekt_test_erp/project%20documents/project%20rate.xsn
```

site with the web part:

```
http://lp/sites/project/default.aspx
```

This is how I set the .xsn file in c#:

```
XmlFormView xmlFormView = new XmlFormView();
xmlFormView.XsnLocation = "http://lp/pwa/projekt_test_erp/project%20documents/project%20rate.xsn";
```

After deploy I get this error:

> “The following location is not accessible, because it is in a
>   different site collection.”

Why I can’t access .xsn from a different site collection? Is there any way to make it work?

I’m working on this problem for about 3 days – any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should deploy the .xsn file in the target site collection as well, since its just a Form Template...

Comment: I can't. It's customer's requirement (those two site collections) and I can't move this file from one to the other. That's the problem.

Comment: Don't move, just copy them in both of the site collections?

Comment: This file can be only in one location (in one site collection) - I can't copy, move etc. this .xsn.